# Test that a returned string is of a certain length with Mockito

Tags: java, string, junit, mocking, mockito

There's a method with several parameters that returns a String. In many conditions the method throws an exception. When it does return, the contents of the String are dependent on both the parameters and on the configuration of a certain USB dongle plugged into the computer. The length of the returned String is entirely dependent on the parameters though.

What I'm wondering is how to unit test this using Mockito (which I'm new to). One of the test methods should complete successfully when the returned String is of a certain length.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 10):

Having such interface:

```
interface Foo {
    void method(String s);
}
```

One idea is to use regular expression matching:

```
final Foo mock = mock(Foo.class);
mock.method("abc");
verify(mock).method(matches(".{3}"));
```

Unfortunately there is no built-in matcher for string length (there should be!), but it's easy to write custom one:

```
private static String hasSize(final int size) {
    return argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            return argument.toString().length() == size;
        }
    });
}
```

Now simply call static method:

```
verify(mock).method(hasSize(4));
```

Answer (score 4):

Tomasz's Answer is perfectly fine if you want to stick with Hamcrest. Plus he used a method that describe what is the intention instead of inserting the anonymous class in your verification code. +1 for his answer :)

But there's an alternative with [FESTAssert](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki/One-minute-starting-guide) library and `ArgumentCaptor` that could offer many more simple assertions without having to write one, and in a fluent way. When you have many assertions, it becomes kind of uneasy with Hamcrest. So here's what I'm using most of the time :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTypeTest {

    @Mock MyType myType;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> stringCaptor;

    @Test public void ensure_method_receive_String_that_has_32_chars() {
        // given
        ...
        // when
        ...
        // then
        verify(myType).method(stringCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(stringCaptor.getValue()).isNotNull().hasSize(32);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't even need FESTAssert.  Just replace that last line with good old JUnit's `assertEquals(32, stringCaptor.getValue().length());`  Note that this will give an NPE if the value is null, but that's probably OK, because it will still be a failure of the test.  If that concerns you, you can precede it with `assertNotNull(stringCaptor.getValue());` or similar.

Comment: Agreed, nevertheless the value of Hamcrest or FestAssert is they provide more focused assertions in the API and in their reported failures on the type they are asserting.

Comment: Thanks Brice and David. I'm leaning toward this answer simply because (as a Mockito n00b) I haven't yet been able to get Tomasz' code to compile. However, I want to test that the method returns (not *receives* as a parameter) a string that has X characters. Also to be more specific: X only depends on the length of the first parameter (which is a String), and there are four parameters. How would the answer be modified accordingly, if it needs to be modified?

Comment: Well what you want is a bit of a different story. If I understood correctly you want your mocked method to return a string that is a function of the input string. Then it doesn't make sense to verify the returned string as this your mock; i.e when you stub it, you pass the returned value. The simpliest thing is to write a deterministic test with fixed fixture and result, a simple case where you can use the `given().willReturn` stubs. If you have possible unmanaged variations in the data, you could write an answer that perform what you want `given(mock.method(anyString).will(use_your_answer())`

Comment: Though my last sentence probably suggests that the production code is still way too much coupled, and might need more work to let emerge different roles that coupled be composed togehter with DI.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 you can check the length with this one-liner:

```
verify(yourMock).theMethod(argThat(a -> a.toString().length() == LENGTH));
```

(using `import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.argThat;`)